# How to open windows explorer from current working directory of WSL shell?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I type "bash" to the windows explorer address bar and hit Enter, it opens the shell in that directory. Often I find myself wanting to work on files with windows programs in the working directory I reached through shell. Is there an easy way to open explorer from the location reached through shell?

Comment: lets say I navigate in shell to /mnt/c/Users/adam/Dropbox/folder and I want to work in that directory, I would like to open explorer at that exact location

Answer (score 168, accepted):

To **open the current directory in Explorer** - use the following (WSL sets the Windows path by itself):

```bash
explorer.exe .
```

---

You can **set alias** with `.bashrc` for a custom command:

```bash
echo 'alias explorer="explorer.exe ."' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Now just use:

```bash
explorer
```

to open the current working directory in Windows Explorer.

Comment: This opens explorer to C:\Windows\System32 folder. Am I missing something?

Comment: @panta82, if you run this comand inside linux emulated directory, explorer.exe can't interprete path to it, so it opens default location.

But in future releases Microsoft team promises to integrate linux directories in to windows explorer, so it possible to start working then.

Comment: it just opens system32 folder no matter where i open it from unless i'm in mnt/ then it opens correct counter part

Comment: @Umer, yes thats right, you can't open linux emulated directory, only mounted mnt/. But you can link to /mnt/c/any_win_path with symbol link: `ln -s` in linux home, then it works inside home.

Comment: alias explorer='explorer.exe `wslpath -w "$PWD"`'

Comment: The comments probably don't reflect current status (2021). WSL open linux emulated directory in explore.exe properly now. wslpath is only required if you need to pass the path around.

Answer (score 41):

Microsoft provides a binary `wslpath` for exactly this purpose.

```
explorer.exe `wslpath -w "$PWD"`
```

Cribbing from [the github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2715) asking for usage info, there are 4 options - `-a`, `-u`, `-w` and `-m`.

```
wslpath usage:
    -a    force result to absolute path format
    -u    translate from a Windows path to a WSL path (default)
    -w    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path
    -m    translate from a WSL path to a Windows path, with ‘/’ instead of ‘\\’

    EX: wslpath ‘c:\users’
```

Comment: is there opposote for wslpath? ex. to pass convert path from windows in wsl?

Comment: @Psychozoic that would be `wslpath -u` to convert from a windows path to a wsl path

Comment: Nice. So you can create a bash `open <path>` command by adding the following to ~/.bash_aliases:  `function open` { explorer.exe \`wslpath -w "$1"\` }

Comment: But when do you need this? `explorer.exe .` also works just fine.

Comment: Well, at time of answer `explorer.exe .` did not work just fine. And while it's now magic, other commands will still require the use of `wslpath`.

Answer (score 31):

For WSL2 you can access to home directory from windows like this :

```
\\wsl$
```

Sorry to be late at the party!

Comment: Nice tip, but it doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `wslview` like this to open an explorer instance in CWD

```
wslview .
```

It is a feature from [wslutilities](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu) and comes installed by default in newer Ubuntu WSL distros. It can be [installed](https://github.com/wslutilities/wslu#installation) in almost all other popular distros.

Comment: underrated answer

Comment: This is the answer for WSL2; the accepted answer probably only works under WSL1.

Answer (score 5):

I have created a little tool called `eopen` to open Explorer easily.
https://github.com/ko1nksm/eopen

```
Usage: eopen [options] [file | directory | uri]

options:
  -e, --editor      Open the file in text editor ($EOPEN_EDITOR)
  -n, --new         Open the specified directory in new instance of explorer
      --sudo        Use sudo to write the unowned file
  -v, --version     Display the version
  -h, --help        You're looking at it

note:
  The file or the directory allows linux and windows path.
  (e.g. /etc/hosts, C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts)

  The uri must start with protocol schema. (e.g http:, https:)
```

And here are another solution.
https://github.com/4U6U57/wsl-open

Comment: This looks awesome!

Answer (score 4):

From a WSL shell prompt, run

```
explorer.exe "Windows path"
```

such as

```
explorer.exe L:
```

If **L:** maps to your desired directory (any unused drive letter may be used for this). You can map to network drives within Explorer, or to a local folder with [SUBST](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst).

Problem is, your /home/USERNAME/ folder in WSL appears to Windows something like C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\tester . You could use SUBST to turn this into a drive letter a la
`SUBST L: C:\Users\YOURUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.Ubuntu18.04onWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\tester`  then use a relative path from L: for your destination.

Let's say you have a WSL folder `/home/YOURUSERNAME/acme/novelties` . You could get close to there with `explorer.exe L:` but `explorer.exe L:acme` or `explorer.exe acme\novelties` will not bring you to where you wish to be, and instead will bring you to your Windows user Documents folder, instead.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the best of partial answers above from @sole-sensei and @laverya, add the following alias to your ~/.bash_aliases (or if for some strange reason you don't want/have a separate aliases file, ~/.bashrc):

```
 alias explorer='explorer.exe `wslpath -w "$PWD"`'
```

If you don't mind tagging it onto the end (I don't because I like to keep it clean and organized):

```
 echo 'alias explorer="explorer.exe ."' >> ~/.bash_aliases
 source ~/.bash_aliases
```

Now if we could just get the new Windows Terminal to support <kbd>ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl-V</kbd> (right-click?! Really Microsoft?!?) we'd be really set!

Answer (score 2):

Setup by running this command :

```
echo "alias open='explorer.exe'" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Usage :

```
open 'directory name'
```

While similar to previous answers it allows you to manually define the path which is more usual for command line tools.  Also I find this more intuitive and quicker to type than 'explorer'.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the command `cmd.exe /c start .` when upon you should see file explorer open in the dir you are in.

```
damo@laptop:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ pwd
/mnt/c/Windows/System32    
damo@laptop:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ cmd.exe /c start .
  <opens file explorer in c:\Windows\System32>
damo@laptop:/mnt/c/Windows/System32$ cd ~
damo@laptop:~$ pwd
/home/damo
damo@laptop:~$ cmd.exe /c start .
  <opens file explorer in c:\Windows\System32>
damo@laptop:~$ cd /mnt/c/stuff
damo@laptop:~$ cmd.exe /c start .
  <opens file explorer in c:\stuff>
```

I set up the following to create an alias `alias start='cmd.exe /c start` which then allow you to simply run `start .` from any directory.

Answer (score 1):

This is my version of the code

```
explorer() {
    pwd -P | xargs wslpath -w | sed "s~C:\\\Users\\\User\\\Desktop~d:~" | xargs -0 explorer.exe
}
```

I use `subst` drives in Windows. The `sed` part convert this for you. If you don't use the feature, you can exclude it.

Note: I posted this answer even though there are many already because none of them covers `symlink` or `subst` drives.

Answer (score 1):

Add this function below to your `.bashrc`:

```sh
e(){
    path=$(wslpath -w "$1")
    /mnt/c/Windows/explorer.exe "$path"
}
```

Comment: Please don't use `path` as a variable name. In my case it overrode the original PATH on zsh and the shell pretty much unusable after running `e`

Answer (score 0):

A note about this `explorer.exe .` command: Found that it allows writing to home directory *only*. I wanted to edit some files in `/etc/apache2`, but it does not allow write there.

So my quick solution was to save to profile folder, then move with `sudo mc` utility to where I needed it to go.

Comment: This answer might be helpful, but at the end you appended a new question: “
anyone - best simple "ctrl-v, ctrl-c" supporting editor? i fear vim, till now i use mc built in editor” I removed that and sadly I don’t think that can stand alone as a new question because it is an opinion-based software recommendation question. Perhaps you can use Nano? Lots of command line editors out there.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue to open windows directory with the `explorer.exe` command  from within `wsl` shell. The error message is `/mnt/c/system32/explorer.exe: permission denied`. It turns out that I need to add the following to `wsl.config` (need `sudo vim` to edit) and restart:

```
[interop]
enable = true
appendWindowsPath = true

[filemask]
umask = 00
```