# How to directly open the WSL bash (command line) to the current working directory from File (Windows) explorer

Tags: bash, windows-explorer, shell, cmd.exe, windows-subsystem-for-linux

My question is the exact opposite of the question [How to open windows explorer from current working directory of WSL shell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1338991/).

When I am at specific directory in Windows explorer, typing `cmd` from the address bar opens the `cmd` at that directory. In this example working directory is `C:\users`.

[image]

Is there a way to do similarly to to open `wsl` shell command line at the working File explorer? That is, to open the below wsl command line:

[image]

Typing and running just `bash` or `wsl` from the address bar, open the wsl command line, but not at the current working directory.

Comment: Typing just `wsl` into File Exploer does open in the directory that Explorer is viewing for me.  Do you perhaps have something in one of your startup scripts (e.g. `~/.bashrc`) that changes the directory?

Comment: Hmm - Re-reading your question, it works when you first start `cmd`, then `wsl` from within that CMD session, so that would mean that it couldn't be a startup file that's overriding it.  Not sure then ...

Comment: Also .. `bash` pulls of the same thing for me in addition to WSL.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I edited the question accordingly. You are right, it seems that even through `cmd` then running `wsl` or `bash` I cannot go to that directory.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @Name Okay, then that does sound like something in a startup file is changing it.  From CMD, if you run `wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc`, does it then start in the current working directory?  If so, then that would be fairly conclusive, I believe, that something in one of your startup files is causing the issue.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `wsl -e bash --noprofile --norc` starts in the root of `wsl`, the directory containing `bin  boot  dev  etc  home  init  lib  lib32  lib64  libx32  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var`.

Comment: @Name Okay, that seems to indicate that it is *not* something to do with the startup config then.  Does the same happen from PowerShell?  I expect that it will, but running out of ideas ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I confirm that when from powershell I fire `bash` or `wsl`, it starts in the current directory.

Comment: @Name Curiouser and curiouser ...  Okay, so PowerShell works as expected, but CMD does not.  Does `where wsl` (in CMD) and `get-command wsl` (in PowerShell) point to the same location?

Comment: Also, `doskey /macros` (in CMD) doesn't show WSL in there, right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds `where wsl` and `doskey /macros` give no result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138054/discussion-between-notthedr01ds-and-name).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "cmd" write "wsl" in the adress bar.

---

### Second try:

Sorry, I have overseen the last line in the original text, probably because it was after the screenshots.
Please, use the following command on the command line to check if your registry has the following keys:

1. WSL-key:

```
reg query HKCR\Directory\shell\WSL
```

The content on my computer (unchanged from me) is:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\WSL
    (Default)    REG_SZ    @wsl.exe,-2
    Extended    REG_SZ
    NoWorkingDirectory    REG_SZ
```

2. The starting command:

```
reg query HKCR\Directory\shell\WSL\command
```

The content should be:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\WSL\command
    (Default)    REG_SZ    wsl.exe --cd "%V"
```

As you can see, here is a "hiden" change-directory-command (`cd`) and a parameter.

Similarly, query the respective key for drives:

```
reg query HKCR\Drive\shell\WSL\command
```

If you get the following error:

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
```

something is wrong with your installation of wsl. Changing the values of the mentioned keys could solve the problem, but is not trivial, because they are protected and only the `trusted installer` can change them. IMHO it will be easier to deactivate the WSL in the windows features, reboot, activate it again and reboot again.

A workaround (and probably easier solution) can be to define a new key

```
reg add HKCR\Directory\shell\WSL_here\command /ve /d "wsl.exe --cd \"%V\""
```

in a command-prompt-window with elevated privilege, of course. This should insert in Windows explorer immediately a new entry in the right-click menu on any directory, which would start a wsl in that directory by selecting/clicking.

Comment: `It could be that the context menu was extended with this command from the Microsoft's "PowerToys"` .. Context menu entries like this aren't complicated.  Like 2 registry keys "not that complicated".  Could simply be added for "WSL Bash Here" but this isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: Just try it. It really opens the WSL in the terminal, and the current directory is as desired. It does not work, though, for UNC directories, only for the local drives!